# Effect of Many(!) Small Queries Being Performed

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, connection-pooling

So I am troubleshooting some performance problems on a legacy application, and I have uncovered a pretty specific problem (there may be others).

Essentially, the application is using an object relational mapper to fetch data, but it is doing so in a very inefficient/incorrect way.  In effect, it is performing a series of entity graph fetches to fill a datagrid in the UI, and on databinding the grid (it is ASP.Net Webforms) it is doing additional fetches, which lead to other fetches, etc.

The net effect of this is that many, many tiny queries are being performed.  Using SQL Profiler shows that a certain page performs over 10,000 queries (to fill a single grid.  No query takes over 10ms to complete, and most of them register as 0ms in Profiler.  Each query will use and release one connection, and the series of queries would be single-threaded (per http request).

I am very familiar with the ORM, and know exactly how to fix the problem.

My question is: what is the exact effect of having many, many small queries being executed in an application?  In what ways does it/can it stress the different components of the system?

For example, what is the effect on the webserver's CPU and memory?  Would it flood the connection pool and cause blocking?  What would be the impact on the database server's memory, CPU and I/O?

I am looking for relatively general answers, mainly because I want to start monitoring the areas that are likely to be the most affected (I need to measure => fix => re-measure).  Concurrent use of the system at peak would likely be around 100-200 users.

Comment: Have you looked at implementing some form of caching?  If the data doesn't change often the entire view/tables can be cached saving all the individual queries.

Comment: @Yzmir--thanks, but I'm not really looking for a solution to the problem (I have that), but more for a way to measure it before and after.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on the database but generally there is a parse phase for each query.  If the query has used bind variables it will probably be cached.  If not, you wear the hit of a parse and that often means short locks on resources.  i.e. BAD.  In Oracle, CPU and blocking are much more prevelant at the parse than the execute.  SQL Server less so but it's worse at the execute.  Obviously doing 10K of anything over a network is going to be a terrible solution, especially x 200 users. Volume I'm sure is fine but that frequency will really highlight all the overhead in comms latency and stuff like that.  Connection pools generally are in the hundreds, not tens of thousands, and now you have 10s of thousands of objects all being created, queued, managed, destroyed, garbage collected etc.

But I'm sure you already know all this deep down.  Ditch the ORM for this part and write a stored procedure to execute the single query to return your result set.  Then put it on the grid.

Comment: Without knowing more about the ORM, I'd say it's a little bold to mandate ditching it. Under the right hands it might be possible to make it perform a single query for a single page (which in my mind is good enough if you don't want to be spreading logic over more tiers).

Comment: Yeah, let me clarify. Ditch the ORM [for this page/part of the page] if you can't make it either construct or use the single query that returns your results.

Comment: The ORM ha nothing to do with it--case of the right tool in the wrong hands.